# MapToDouble equivalent with C# Dictionary

Tags: java, c#

I have become familiar with functional programming in Java over the last year. I am now trying my hands with C# with a test program that I have lightly working in Java. I would like to migrate this to C# and I have run into a roadblock while working with a Dictionary to try and mimic what I did with a Map in Java.

That roadblock is trying to find an equivalent to Java's .mapToDouble function while working with a Hashmap stream.

In java:

```
stream().mapToDouble(statistics -> getRuntime(statistics)).sum()
```

What would I use in C# to take a dictionary and map an object to a double such that I can get the sum of it?

Comment: You want to sum dobule values from a dictonary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like, according to your description, you have a dictionary of some key `TKey` and a value of `object`.

```
var sampleDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, object>();
... populate dictionary ...
```

We don't really care about the keys. If your `object` instance types are convertible to `double`s, then you could do a couple different things:

```
// Perform a LINQ operation on the `Values` collection of the dictionary:
var sum = sampleDictionary.Values.Select(v => Convert.ToDouble(v)).Sum();
```

Or

```
// Perform a LINQ operation directly on the dictionary
// Use this is if you might potentially need to incorporate TKey into your result
var sum = sampleDictionary.Select(d => Convert.ToDouble(d.Value)).Sum();
```

You can also move the lambda in to the `.Sum()` function if you like, to shorten it:

```
var sum = sampleDictionary.Values.Sum(v => Convert.ToDouble(v));
```

Or

```
var sum = sampleDictionary.Sum(d => Convert.ToDouble(d.Value));
```

No one way is really better than the other here, just pick one that works now and makes sense in the context of your application.

If your `objects` might not be convertible to `double`, then let us know in a comment, as this will have to be refactored a little.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. The key object is not directly convertible to a double. It contains a double field with a getter that returns the field value.

So I imagine I can do:
var sum = sampleDictionary.Values.Sum(v => Convert.toDouble(v.getRuntime()));

Where v.getRuntime() will return a double value from my object.

Comment: I apparently need to learn how to format comments too lol. This is my first time posting anything meaningful on here.

Comment: If `v.getRuntime()` already returns a true `double`, you can omit the `Convert.ToDouble()` portion. Otherwise, what you imagined you could do is exactly right!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Linq `Sum()` to get sum of the values of dictionary items:

```
double sum = dict.Sum(d => d.Value);
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5wYSSY)

Comment: Wow. That live demo is an awesome way to leave a comment. Thank you so much for taking the time to set that up...I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer to my question is to simply LINQ .sum on my dictionary. I received two answers of that sort but I could only accept one of them.

To provide more context for what I was attempting to do...

```html
beestatData.Data.Where(datum => 
      isWithinDateRange(new DateTime((int)datum.Year, (int)datum.Month, (int)datum.Day), startDate, endDate))
      .Sum(datum => datum.AuxiliaryHeat1/60/60);
```

I am not only messing around with C# for the first time but I am also trying to use JSON to grab data from my Ecobee thermostat. To tailor the data in various ways, I ended up with a bunch of different functions that would grab the data and manipulate it within loops. I decided this was getting messy and figured that the use of functional programming was the way to go.

I found out that .Where is roughly equivalent to .filter in Java but I was doubtful that .Sum was the same as .mapToDouble.Sum(). I'm glad to see that the answer is this simple and now I can easily grab the total runtime of my system within a certain set of dates.

Note: This does not yet compile and work but I believe that is due to something else in my code.